# Joining mininet hosts to Active DIrectory VM

Tags: virtual-machine, active-directory, domain

I am trying to add mininet hosts to domain in a test environment. I have a host OS (WIn 10) with 2 VMs. One mininet VM and the other WIndows Server 2012 VM which is domain controller. I want the mininet hosts to join the domain. First of all I am unable to reach AD VM from the hosts. Please guide that I am working in the right direction and it is possible for mininet hosts to be part of domain.

Comment: The title of this site is "Unix & Linux". How did you think this would be the right place to ask? This looks off-topic.

Comment: Well its primarily related to mininet which in based on linux. dont find it off topic. let me where exactly to ask then?

Comment: Probably https://superuser.com/ , but you have to read (whatever stackexchange site) the help: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic . The question should also include some details and the efforts you already put into the problem. Also, there shouldn't be cross-posted question ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu ) so if asked again elesewhere, it should be deleted here.